# How to order data on Inner Join MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a case to create podcast playlist based on category sorts. For example, I want to join podcast data and category data based on the table below.

```
> SELECT * FROM category_sorts;

+----+-------------+------+
| id | category_id | sort |
+----+-------------+------+
|  1 |           2 |    1 |
|  2 |           1 |    2 |
|  3 |           1 |    3 |
|  4 |           2 |    4 |
+----+-------------+------+
```

Column `category_id` related to categories table.

```
> SELECT * FROM categories;

+----+--------------+-----------+
| id | title        | status    |
+----+--------------+-----------+
|  1 | Saga         | published |
|  2 | Asia Calling | published |
+----+--------------+-----------+
```

And here some sample data from `podcasts` table with a related category.

```
> SELECT * FROM podcasts;

+----+-------------+------------------------+---------------------+
| id | category_id | title                  | published_at        |
+----+-------------+------------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |           1 | Sejarah Rumah Dengklok | 2018-05-01 22:40:47 |
|  3 |           2 | Berita Asia!           | 2018-05-01 22:52:15 |
|  4 |           2 | Asia Later!            | 2018-05-01 23:47:13 |
|  5 |           1 | Saga terbaru           | 2018-05-02 00:06:32 |
+----+-------------+------------------------+---------------------+
```

Using the provided query below, I got duplicate podcasts in the same category sorts.

```
SELECT
        p.id, p.title AS podcast_title, p.published_at, 
        c.title AS category_title,
        cs.sort
    FROM podcasts as p
    INNER JOIN categories as c ON c.id = p.category_id
    INNER JOIN category_sorts AS cs on cs.category_id = c.id
    GROUP BY cs.sort
    ORDER BY cs.sort ASC, p.published_at DESC
```

Results:

```
+----+------------------------+---------------------+----------------+------+
| id | podcast_title          | published_at        | category_title | sort |
+----+------------------------+---------------------+----------------+------+
|  3 | Berita Asia!           | 2018-05-01 22:52:15 | Asia Calling   |    1 |
|  1 | Sejarah Rumah Dengklok | 2018-05-01 22:40:47 | Saga           |    2 |
|  1 | Sejarah Rumah Dengklok | 2018-05-01 22:40:47 | Saga           |    3 |
|  3 | Berita Asia!           | 2018-05-01 22:52:15 | Asia Calling   |    4 |
+----+------------------------+---------------------+----------------+------+
```

What I expect?

I want to order playlist based on `sort` column and latest podcasts indicated by `published_at` column. Order using `sort` column is OK, but I can't order it by `published_at` date from podcasts.

Can someone give me a clue how to do with it? Any link or source will be appreciated.

[Here is](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3672ce/2/0) example full table structure and data from SQL Fiddle if you want to play with it.

Thank you.

Comment: A +1 for an absolutely stellar first question - complete with SQLFiddle!

Comment: Your first problem is your categories_sort table. The data doesn't make sense. Each category_id should only have one sort value, not multiple.

Comment: I want to create playlist like this image: https://s31.postimg.cc/3keqwfjfv/3b623f74-497d-464c-b57a-bb4834029143.png. So, it's possible using one or more same category in a playlist.